# How to iterate over a column in a Pandas DF to check for a certain value and return a value in the same row but from a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

The df contains event based football data. So what I'm looking to do is iterate over the action_name column and look for the value 'goal' if found I then want to store values from multiple other columns that are in the same row as the 'goal' action name. Below is an example of the structure of the data.

[image: data structure]

So in this case I want to return the pos_dest_x, pos_dest_y and the possesion_number for every goal in the DF and store them as new DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various ways of doing so :

```
columns_wanted = ['pos_dest_x','pos_dest_y','possession_number']

# 1
df.loc[df.action_name == 'Goal'][columns_wanted]

# 2 
df[df.action_name == 'Goal'][columns_wanted]

# 3
df.query('action_name == "Goal"')[columns_wanted]
```

In case 1 and 2 you can do either `df.action_name` or `df['action_name']`

You will find more information here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
df.loc[df["action_name"]=="Goal", ["pos_dest_x", "pos_dest_y", "possesion_number"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your df has the name `actions_df`, you should be able to run something like:

```
goals_df = actions_df[actions_df['action_name']=="Goal"][['pos_dest_x','pos_dest_y','possession_number']]
```

Which selects rows from the `actions_df` where action_name is equal to goal, and the filters the columns down to the ones you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is called df. You can do:

```
reduced_dataset = df[df['action_name']=='Goal']
```

This will yield you the dataset where the action is Goal.